# Unable to enable Tomcat 8.0.45 log in debug mode

Tags: tomcat8

I am starting tomcat from java code as given below.

```
bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
String [] a = {"-config",serverXmlPath};
bootstrap.init(a);
bootstrap.setAwait(true);
bootstrap.start();
```

and i want to enable tomcat logs in debug mode.
I tried changing the conf/catalina.properties but it is not reflecting any changes.

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE

org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.level = FINEST

org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
```

Could you please help me to get out of this issue.